How works auto crypto assets stolen web pages
In my dissertation, I learned about the tactics of Ethereum scammers and I wanted to know how crypto sites automatically detect "cryptopank", "bored monkey", coins, etc., and automatically send them to another wallet before you can do anything?
Can you provide information on how these schemes work and how they are implemented? I wanted to write all of this in my dissertation and post it here for the community to see if anyone needs the information in the future.
Thank you

What do you mean? Sweeper bots are a well known tools to retrieve funds. I don't think hackers do anything different to obtain private keys or mnemonics: social engineering, malware, fake pages, phishing, etc.

I had to deal with the fact that after logging into the wallet page and pressing the "connect" button, and I not execute transaction and my NFTs and tokens disappeared within 5 minutes. Losing ~$200, no big deal, but I don't even understand how they did it

@EligijusGirdenis you didn't only connect the wallet, you must have signed some message of some sort, which is generally a "permit" signature.

I had to sign a paid transaction?
